# jQuery Mobile: Which event should listview('refresh') go in?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'm developing an application which uses WebSQL DB to store data and then retrieve it.
The UI is powered by jQuery Mobile, and when I successfully get back the data from the DB, I put it in a listview.

When I do that, I get the data, but with no styling at all. Just plain web browser rendering.

To refresh the layout, I looked on jQuery Mobile Docs that I need to use `$('#list').listview('refresh');`

Now I tried several implementations of this and always failed. I'm asking, **which event** should the refresh statement go in.
On my page load I load the Data and put it in the DOM.

Please Help!...
Thanks...

Comment: what is the error (if any), http://jsfiddle.net or a demo code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This may not be the best way, but I found a solution.

I made a function which I hooked up to body's onload event. That seems to work.

So till anyone else doesn't give me a better solution, I might continue using that...

Answer (score 0):

Try $('#list').listview(); to initialize it, you only call refresh if you added li elements and need those to be styled.

Comment: I figured out that I need to call $('#list').listview(); to Init it. But the point is which even should it be triggered?
Right now I hooked up an onLoad event on the body. Is that a good way or should I change?

Comment: pageinit is jQM's equivalent to jQuery's $(document.ready) which is the preferred method over the onload event in the body. If the ul is populated server side and already in your html you should be able to just add data-role="listview" to your ul and not have to even call listview() on it. If you added this ul dynamically then you need to call listview(). If you added new li elements after calling listview(), then you need to call listview('refresh') hope that clears it up

Comment: thanks for the explanation... just one more question, should i use bind or live for the pageinit event?
Thanks... :D